# openX Ad server not displaying the banner in email body

Tags: php, openx

i have created a banner in openx and linked it with zone. Type of zone is Email/Newsletter zone and get its invocation code and paste its code in email body but i don't get banner in email body at receiver end. It gives error showing all invocation code instead of banner

Email Body :-

```
<htm>
    <body>
        <a href='http://mysite/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?zoneid=9' target='_blank'>
            <img src='http://mysite/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=9&amp;cb=452745' border='0' alt='' />
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

i have also used simple php mail function to send mail.

Comment: Body looks truncated. Can you specify here complete version that is sent to user?

Comment: Besides, are you sure that the there are no problems with sending mail with `mail()`? It has some caveats too.

Comment: Openx version is 2.8.10 and php version is 5.3.3 and i am able to receive mail but at receiver end it displayed invocation code instead of banner linked with code.

Comment: [OT] What users do still allow external images in emails to be displayed nowadays ...?

Answer (score 0):

Links for inserting should be similar with this:

```
<a href="http://mysite/openx/www/delivery/ck.php?n=__CODE__&cb=__RAND__">
    <img src="http://mysite/openx/www/delivery/avw.php?n=__CODE__&cb=__RAND__&zoneid=__ZONEID__"/>
</a>
```

where:

```
__CODE__ - 8digits hash, __RAND__ - random number, __ZONEID__ - zoneId.
```

In both urls **CODE** and **RAND** must be equal